# Improving Normalizing Flows Accuracy

Tags: accuracy, generative-models

What are some techniques one might use to improve the accuracy of normalizing flows? I am training a flow in a high-dimensional space but it seems like there's always at least one or two dimensions in which the new generated points seem to be very inaccurate, even when other dimensions seem to be generated with a high degree of accuracy.